# React Native Border Css

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-styleguidist

I'm a very beginner at react-native. I'm trying to design like the image given below. But can't make the red marked part. Can anyone help me to solve this by saying what CSS property should I use to design this part? I know I have to use border-radius but can't reach out what would be the other property for making the appropriate design like the image given.

[image]

Comment: You can use `box-shadow` which I think that will create your goal; Try this `box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);`

Comment: Also try this which more responsive; `box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `box-shadow` property (Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow))

```css
.card {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px -1px #58585838;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your code so we can see where's the problem?
But you can use these `properties` to change it:

```
borderBottomRightRadius:value,
borderBottomLeftRadius:value
```

Example:

```
borderBottomRightRadius:10
```

Comment: How can i set shadow at bottom

Comment: Check this link :https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/

Comment: If it doesn't help you , i think this one will : https://medium.com/game-development-stuff/how-to-apply-shadows-on-react-native-fa745d374ae7